# PHP form doesn't distinguish between a and ǎ

Tags: php, comparison

I have a form written in PHP. recently I found out that users can replace `a` with `ǎ` (letters with accented letters) and still login without problem, and the form can't distinguish. What is the problem?
( I've heard something about `==` and `===`, but I'm not sure)

P.S: I'm very new to PHP!

Comment: Post the code you have

Comment: This is nothing to do with `==` and `===`, it's all to do with people who don't understand accented characters and so change them to their unaccented equivalent.... the problem is that the people who wrote your form didn't know how to handle accented characters correctly, so they just created a lazy (and bad) workround

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 I don't have the code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't PHP that is poorly doing the comparison:

```
<?php

    echo ('a' == 'ǎ')?"Looks the same!":"Who you kidding?";
    echo ('a' === 'ǎ')?"Looks the same!":"Who you kidding?";

?>
```

OUtput:

```
Who you kidding?
Who you kidding?
```

There is some additional work at play here. If the form is being submitted and then handling the information before it passes it back to the rest of your code - you need to look into it in detail. Who knows what else it is changing?

If you have the plugin on your site, you have the code already - just look into what it is doing.